# Items from file in itemize environment

Tags: macros, lists, itemize, external-files

Is it possible to import items from a file into an itemize environment? For example, consider a file with just words and no formatting:

```
Elem1
Elem2
Elem3
Elem4
...
Elem120933
```

I like to read in this file and place it in an `itemize`, `enumerate`, etc. I bet this can be done via a macro but not sure how to approach it.

[Note this is an exact question from StackOverflow that hasn't been answered and is of interest to me.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25684120/363829)

Comment: you can use fancyvrb package

Answer (score 7):

```
\documentclass{article}


\newread\myread% Get a file handle grip, call it myread


\newcommand{\openandtypeset}[1]{%
\IfFileExists{#1}{%  Check first
\openin\myread=#1  % Open the file from #1 
\begin{itemize}
\loop
\read\myread to \localvariable   % Read line content to `\localvariable`
\ifeof\myread  % Is it at the end of the file -> localvariable is empty effectively --> do not use \item then
\else
\item \localvariable % Typeset the local item
\repeat
\end{itemize}
\closein\myread%  Close the file. 
}{}% End of \IfFileExists
}

\begin{document}
\openandtypeset{itemfromfile.txt}

\end{document}
```

Here is the `itemfromfile.txt` file

```
This is 
a \LaTeXe
list
read
from
file
```

**Edit** A slightly improved version:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newread\myread% Get a file handle grip called \myread


\newcommand{\loaditemsfromfile}[2][enumerate]{%
\IfFileExists{#2}{%
  \openin\myread=#2
  \begin{#1}  % Use an itemize enviroment with #1 as name of the env. 
    \loop\unless\ifeof\myread%
    \read\myread to \localvariable
    \ifeof\myread
    \else
  \item \localvariable
    \fi
    \repeat
  \end{#1} % close the environment
  \closein\myread%  \close the file
}{}%
}

\begin{document}
\loaditemsfromfile{itemfromfile.txt}

\loaditemsfromfile[itemize]{itemfromfile.txt}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do not use empty lines after the last 'text line' -- otherwise the loop will read those empty lines too

Comment: Just a minor remark: `\immediate` is redundant with `\openin` and `\closein`.  EDIT: Also, if you check for `\ifeof` you don’t need to use `\IfFileExists` (which is actually implemented by means of `\ifeof`) .

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti: Thanks for remarks. I know that `\immediate\read` is useless (or even wrong), but I saw `\immedate\openin` etc. a lot of times. But the `\ifeof` is need to end the loop, isn't it? The `\IfFileExists` is an outside test of course

Comment: What I meant is that, if the file being opened does not exist, `\ifeof` will immediately return “true”, so you can treat the the two cases of an empty file and of a nonexistent file together, which is usually the right thing to do.  Regarding `\immediate\openin`, it is definitely an error, no matter how many times, and by whom (or Whom), you have seen it being used.  See chapter 24 of _The TeXbook_ (top of page 280).

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti: I believe you, removing `\immediate` then. For the `\ifeof` I will change the code later on

Comment: Well, after all `\IfFileExists` too wll treat the two cases of an empty file and of a nonexistent file together, since it does exactly the same thing (`\openin` followed by `\ifeof`)!  Sometimes I am really a silly! ;-)